# Can't access http page on Azure VM

Tags: azure, remote-server, httpserver

I create an Ubuntu VM on Azure. By default in the inbound rules there was only the rule the maps from `*` to `22`.

I changed the rule to `22` (changed the `*` to `22`) and added a rule from `80` to `80`.

Problem is - I can't access an HTTP server that's on the machine. I tried to run `wget http://localhost` and I got the correct `index.html` page. But, when I try to run it form outside, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set inbound 22 to and 80 to 80, also you can create outbound * to *. Don't forget to restart the VM, usually restarting will make it works

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the role to * to 80.
The * indicates the port on the machine initiating the request, where it is selected randomly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work must create an outbound rule as well as inbound for the same port.
Alternatively you can create rules for standard protocols from template (items other than `Custom` in `Service` combobox) instead.